# I am not able to change the model family of my GLM using statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

Here are my lines (in python) for my GLM:

```
#%% GLM
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.GLM(y, X, familiy=sm.families.Poisson())

model_GLM = model.fit()
print(model_GLM.summary())
```

But the summary I get is always set to the default Gaussian distribution no matter what family I specify. Why?